# Bootstrap - Unable to make the page responsive

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have created a website containing a mega menu. However, when I reduce the size of the page, the layout does not seem to be responsive and the elements seem to overflow.

I am unable to post the complete code, please assist. Below are the snippets of the code.

[Full Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCERW.png)

[After reducing size of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLvB0.png)

I want to make the page responsive to any device. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please post the code you have problems with in your question

Answer (score 0):

You should try the [bootstraps column mechanism](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/css-grid/#responsive). I already find the part with tips for responsive design, but you should read it all. You just throughout the HTML classes define, how width you want the thing to be. Maybe, if you're able to put here a little bit from your code, it will be easier to help, but i know, that sometimes, it's just not posible. Anyway i hope, this will help